# pattern match in whole array

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

Could anyone please tell me how to search a pattern in whole array at once
eg

```
@array = ('I am AA','I am BB', 'I am CC', 'I am AAC')
$pattern = "AA"
```

I am using following logic but it is not working

```
if (@array =~ /$pattern/) {
    # do this; 
} else {
    # do that 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `if ("@array" =~ /$pattern/)` if you don't mind array elements being joined by single space `" "`

Answer (score 5):

You're likely looking for a `grep`

```
my @array = ('I am AA','I am BB', 'I am CC', 'I am AAC');
my $pattern = "AA";

if (my @matches = grep {$_ =~ /$pattern/} @array) {
    print "These entries matched:\n";
    print "'$_'\n" for @matches;
    # do this; 

} else {
    # do that 
}
```

However, it is also possible that your pattern will not necessarily work the way that you expect if this is anything like what you're actually matching.  I'd advise that you add a word boundary to your pattern and also [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
if (my @matches = grep {$_ =~ /\b\Q$pattern\E\b/} @array) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Could you please tell me how can I get exact match "AA" but not "AAC". This expression is not working grep {$_=~ /(\w+)\t(\w+)\t([^$pattern$])/}@array

Comment: Getting an exact word match is why I added my extra note about word boundaries `\b`.  Use the second regular expression if you want to be more limiting on what you match.

Comment: There's no need for `$_ =~ `, or the braces, in either `grep`. I find `my @matches = grep /$pattern/, @array` much more readable. But that is IMO

Comment: @Borodin I bet there's a connection to how much someone uses a unix environment for when they have a preference for block format or expr format.  I pretty much always use block since I assume it's less fragile and also provides consistency between `grep`, `map` and `sort`, but was obviously being intentionally more verbose since was aiming to teach.

Comment: @Miller: I use Linux and Windows about equally, but most of my Perl code lives on Ubuntu or Mint. My choice of a block or an expression depends mostly on Perl's syntax and what I think is more readable. So I would write `my %h = map { $_ => 1 } 'a' .. 'x'`, but also `my @letters = grep /[[:alpha:]]/, map chr, 0 .. 255`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
if (grep m/$pattern/, @array) {
    # do something
}
else {
    # do other things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator):

```
my @array = ('I am AA','I am BB', 'I am CC', 'I am AAC');
my $pattern = qr"AA";

if ($pattern ~~ @array) {
    say "Found"; 
} else {
    say "NOT found"; 
}
```